# Does Delphi XE5 support Android Lollipop?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I'm using Delphi XE5. My Android application works on KitKat, but not on Lollipop.  Does Delphi XE5 support Lollipop or not?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in Embarcadero's documentation for XE5:

[Android Devices Supported for Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development)

KitKat is the highest Android version supported in XE5.

Lollipop support was added in XE8, though there is also a [hotfix for XE7](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30110).